# How to "tag" array number with string using a struct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

So I have a loop that takes a line of formatted input that has a name and several numbers and it performs an operation to determine the total score based on those numbers. At the end of the program it is supposed to output the highest score as well as the name of the person who achieved the score. I have a count variable that increases each time it goes through the loop to score the number of the previous "total score" into an array. At the end of the program that array with all the totals is sorted from highest to lowest and then scoretotals[0] is outputted to display the highest score. My question is what is the easiest way to get the name corresponding to that number into a value that can be outputted at the end?

I have tried making a struct and then making that array part of the struct but this brings a lot of errors. So here is my code without attempts to output the name corresponding to the highest score

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <functional>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Name    " << "Diff   " << "Sorted scores                                      " << "Total" << endl;
        struct contestants
        {
            string name;
            double difficulty;
            double score1;
            double score2;
            double score3;
            double score4;
            double score5;
            double score6;
            double score7;
            double score8;
            double score9;
        };
        contestants person;

        ifstream divers ("m6dive.txt");
        int count = 0;



        double scoretotals[50];

        while (divers >> person.name >> person.difficulty >> person.score1 >> person.score2 >> person.score3 >> person.score4 >> person.score5 >> person.score6 >> person.score7 >> person.score8 >> person.score9)
        {


            double scores[9] = { person.score1, person.score2, person.score3, person.score4, person.score5, person.score6, person.score7, person.score8, person.score9 };

            std::sort(scores, scores + 9, std::greater< double >()); //sorts from max to min

            double total = (scores[1] + scores[2] + scores[3] + scores[4] + scores[5] + scores[6] + scores[7]) * person.difficulty; //computes score (total excluding min,max multiplied by score)

            //outputs name, difficulty, scores sorted and total
            cout << person.name << "\t" << std::setprecision(1) << fixed << person.difficulty << "\t" << scores[8] << "\t" << "\t" << scores [7] << " "<<  scores [6] << " " << scores[5] << " " << scores[4] << " " << scores [3] << " " << scores [2] << " " <<scores[1] << " " << scores [0] << "   " << total << endl;


            scoretotals[count] = total;
            count++;
        }

        std::sort(scoretotals, scoretotals + 50, std::greater< double >());
        cout << "Highest score is " << scoretotals[0];

    }
```

Output:

```
Name    Diff   Sorted scores                                      Total
Anne    2.0     8.0             8.0 8.5 8.5 9.0 9.0 9.0 9.5 9.5   123.0
Sarah   3.0     8.5             8.5 8.5 8.5 9.0 9.0 9.0 9.5 9.5   186.0
Jon     1.5     6.0             7.0 7.5 7.5 7.5 8.0 8.5 8.5 8.5   81.8
Highest score is 186.0
. . .
```

Comment: Add `scoretotal` member to `contestants` and use it to hold the contestant's total score. Then sort the list of contestants  by `scoretotal`. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing and sorting `scoretotals`, store and sort `contestant`'s!!

If you add a function for calculating `<`, you can call `sort()` with your own struct!

```
struct less_than_key {
    inline bool operator() (const contestant& c1, const contestant& c2)
    {
        //Consider making a different function to calculate totals to simplify this copy/paste!
        double c1_total = (c1.score1 + ... + c1.score9) * c1.difficulty;
        double c2_total = (c2.score1 + ... + c2.score9) * c2.difficulty;

        return (c1_total < c2_total);
    }
};
```

And then you can sort with:

```
std::sort(people, people + 50, less_than_key());
```

After that, it'd be as simple as pulling out the first person and grabbing their name and total!